# Hyperledger Fabric : duplicated values

Tags: transactions, sdk, duplicates, hyperledger-fabric, peer

I am worknig on hyperledger fabric those days and i am facing many problems : 
So i am using java SDK in order to invoke the blockchain . I have two methods one for sending a proposal to write in the ledger and an other consists in reading from the ledger :  the problem is when i send a writing proposal : each peer validates with a different transactionId so the transaction is saved in the ledger two time .. so when i read it i obtain a duplicated value .... I tried with other chaincodes ... and i got a good validations ... two peers validates the transaction with the same transactionId 
... is that problem is commain ? how can we solve this issue and not having a duplicated values .. also who can explains whay can this happen ?? and thank you very much guys :) :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what's going wrong from the description, but, certainly duplicated data and conflicting transaction IDs are not expected behavior and is likely a bug in the application code invoking the SDK.

When creating a 'writing' transaction, a single proposal should be created (with one txid) to be sent to multiple peers for endorsement.  The resulting endorsements and original proposal are packaged into a transaction (with this same txid) and submitted to ordering.  Eventually, this transaction should commit to the ledger.

When creating 'reading' transactions, a single proposal is created and is (usually) sent only to your own peer.  The results are read, and then discarded, without ever being sent to ordering, so it should never appear on the blockchain.

It sounds to me like perhaps your application is generating a unique proposal (with unique txid) to send to each peer, with the same operations, rather than re-using the same proposal across all peers.